# How to handle inserts from a source spark df to hive table if the number of columns differ

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a pyspark dataframe to hive table but since my source df has only 5 columns and target is having 9 columns, it is resulting in an error.

Also, since there are multiple cases as such I don't want to frame manual insert queries that can solve this issue. I am looking for a better automated way that can handle this problem without manually writing the queries for each case.

I thought of creating a new df in spark by taking the source df and the extra columns that are present in target table but not in source df but its not working the way I thought.

Here is the code that i am working on

```
#extract cols from src df and tgt df(hive table) 
src_cols = df1.columns
tgt_cols = df2.columns

#get the extra cols (diff)
extra_cols = list(set(tgt_cols) - set(src_cols))
#extra_cols = ['state', 'datetime', 'zipcode', 'type']

#formulate the string to add extra cols
string = ""
for item in extra_cols:
    string += str(".withColumn(\""+item+"\", lit(\"NULL\"))")
```

This will print out the required string that i can use for new df

```
#'.withColumn("state", lit(NULL)).withColumn("datetime", lit(NULL)).withColumn("zipcode", lit(NULL)).withColumn("type", lit(NULL))'


new_df = "df1" + string
#'df1.withColumn("state", lit("NULL")).withColumn("datetime", lit("NULL")).withColumn("zipcode", lit("NULL")).withColumn("type", lit("NULL"))'
```

The issue now is that I am unable to execute the code `df1.withColumn("state", lit("NULL")).withColumn("datetime", lit("NULL")).withColumn("zipcode", lit("NULL")).withColumn("type", lit("NULL"))` as it is a string

Can anyone please help me out to handle this scenario in a much better way.

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't mentioned about your target database. Is it a NoSQL DB or a RDBMS?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it in python, but using scala you can create a list with Column objects containing the original columns and `lit("NULL").alias("state")`, etc. Then you can use `df.select(col_list: _*)`.

Comment: @PhaniKumarYadavilli The target is hive table.its already mentioned in the first line .

Comment: What about simply using a SQL `INSERT...SELECT` query to specify which source columns _(from a "temp view")_ are mapped to which target cols? The SQL parser will take care of the Nulls in target cols without a value. And you will get rid of all that nasty Scala boilerplate code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have identified the list of difference in column names as

```
#extra_cols = ['state', 'datetime', 'zipcode', 'type']
```

Then you *don't need to formulate the string to add extra cols*, you can simply use `reduce` function to apply `.withColumn` on the list of column names as

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
to_be_written_df = reduce(lambda temp_df, col_name: temp_df.withColumn(col_name, f.lit('NULL')), extra_cols, df1)
```

That should solve your issue

Comment: There is another thing that is not linked to this question, But can you guide me on auto-Incremental inserts in hive using dataframes

Comment: research for it . If you don't find an answer please ask another question